# How to dismiss camera (ImagePickerController) in a tabbar App and reload it whenever tab is re-selected?

Tags: ios, camera, uitabbarcontroller, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller

I am building an app that shows the camera (`ImagePickerController`) when the tab is selected for the first time. Since it is modally presented by its view controller, it takes the entire screen and I have placed a close button which dismisses the controller and gives access back to the tabs (6 of them). Next time the camera tab is selected though, the camera does not launch but just gives me an empty window, i.e. the View Controller. I have created my app with `Storyboard` and use a custom camera overlay - not the standard `UIImagePickerController` overlay.

I dismiss the camera with:  `[self.picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Can someone kindly guide me on how to always present the camera in this view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is working the first time and not subsequent times, I'm guessing that you are displaying the camera view controller in the `viewDidLoad` method of the tab's view controller.  Move that code to `viewWillAppear` and it should display every time that you go to the tab.

Alternatively, you could display the camera in the `UITabBarDelegate` `tabBar:didSelectItem:` method.

Comment: Moving the code in viewWillAppear did the trick! I should point out though that when I first put the code there, it crashes with the error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller. So, I used a bool variable to stop viewWillAppear the first time but let it load it after the first time it had been launched. Thanks!

Comment: That is a bug that I've seen a couple of times, for no obvious reason.  You shouldn't need to do that though.

Comment: I think ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear are called the first time the view controller is launched. Thereafter only ViewWillAppear is called say you navigate away and had to navigate back to the View Controller. I have actually gotten this same error in the past before but using a variable to distinguish first launch from subsequent ones solved the problem.